# How do I find the derivative of $s=2^{t^2}$?

Tags: calculus

I am doing homework right now and there's this one question that I can't seem to get due to my weak background with logs..

Simply put, it's asking us to find:

$ds/dt$ of $s = 2^{t^2}$

I tried using the known rule of the derivative of $a^x = a^x\ln a$, but that didn't really work out so well...I know the answer has to have a $\ln$ in it, but I never in my life have come across having to derive something of this kind. Can someone provide me with the logic and general rules used and steps if you don't mind.

EDIT:

Alright, I didn't expect so many answers to this trivial question, but I am very thankful for everyone's answers because not everyone's answer's were the same and because of that it showed me multiple ways of doing it! And I learned some new tricks too! Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Chain Rule:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(2^{t^2}\right)=\left(2^{t^2}\ln 2\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(t^2\right)\;,$$

and I leave the last step to you. There’s no need for implicit or logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: What is the objection to the answer?

Comment: I understand we need the chain rule, but I can't grasp the logic using the chain rule with something to the power of something of the power. By the way i am not doing any downvoting or anything.

Comment: @user3718584: It’s simply a composite function. Let $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=2^t$; then $s=g\big(f(t)\big)$, so $\frac{ds}{dt}=g'(f(t))\cdot f'(t)$. It’s no different in principle from differentiating any other composite function: work from the outside in. You already know that the derivative of $2^x$ with respect to $x$ is $2^x\ln 2$; it follows that the derivative of $2^u$ with respect to $x$ is $(2^u\ln 2)\cdot u'$, where $u'$ is the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: In Meta, people were discussing that high rep users should leave these sort of questions to new users to encourage them. Too much vulture around.

Comment: @Pedro: That’s no excuse for misleading users by downvoting correct answers. (It’s also no excuse for anonymous, uncommented downvoting.) Moreover, the two answers that were already present when I answered this are unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: you already have 246K. Why do you need more points? your answer is the same answer as Mario G.

Comment: @Pedro: Mario’s wasn’t visible when I posted mine. Why do you not respond to my substantive points?

Comment: My point, Brian, is that you should leave easy questions to new users.

Comment: @Pedro: Even when the only answers that I see are unnecessarily complicated? No, I don’t think so. And anyone who downvotes a correct answer, knowing that it is correct, is deliberately sabotaging the site.

Comment: When I took derivative of outer fucntion I got 2*t^2 and then the derivative of the inside function is t^2, but how did the ln come about again form the inner function t^2?

Comment: Sabotaging the site is also being pragmatic: Getting points by any method: Answering very easy questions.

Comment: @user3718584: The $\ln 2$ comes from the first step: when you differentiate $2^{u(t)}$ wrt $t$ you get $(2^{u(t)}\ln 2)$ from the outer differentiation and then a factor of $u'(t)$ from the chain rule. In this case you $u(t)=2^t$, so you end up with $2^{t^2}\ln 2$ from the first step and a further factor of $2t$ from the chain rule.

Comment: @Pedro: Your assumptions about my motives are not merely uncharitable but in fact false. I leave the vast majority of easy questions to others. The exceptions are: (1) when I can immediately provide a good hint for a new question; (2) when I think that a detailed paedagogical discussion will help the asker more than a straightforward answer, and no one has yet given one; (3) when I can give an answer that I think significantly better than the existing ones; and (4) when I can give an answer significantly different from the existing ones that I think teaches something useful, and in that ...

Comment: ... case I not infrequently emphasize that the technique of another answer is easier, quicker, or what have you. Anyone, irrespective of ‘reputation’, should feel free to do any of these things: they serve the interests of the askers.

Comment: (3) does not apply here. They were already perfectly good answers before you posted your solution, and in fact, a solution that matched yours exactly, Mario's solution. Furthermore, it seems a copy and paste solution from Mario's

Comment: @Pedro: As I already told you, Mario’s was not visible when I posted mine. Apparently it went up while I was typing. And no, mine is obviously not a copy and paste of his. As for the rest, (3) certainly does apply here: the two answers that I had seen when I posted are correct but unnecessarily complicated, a fact that anyone interested in teaching — which is my primary interest — should consider worth pointing out to a student.

Answer (score 2):

So we have the function $s = 2^{t^2}$.  A good place to start is taking the natural log of both sides, which will allow us to get the $t^2$ out of the exponent:

$$\ln(s) = \ln(2)t^2$$

And now take a derivative with respect to $t$, keeping the chain rule in mind:

$$\frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{ds}}{\operatorname{dt}} = 2\ln(2)t$$

This was most of the battle!  Now it's just a matter of solving for $\displaystyle\frac{\operatorname{ds}}{\operatorname{dt}}$.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?  I certainly appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: I don’t downvote on the main site, so I can only guess: the downvoter may have been objecting to your use of an unnecessarily roundabout approach. A comment to that effect would certainly have been more useful.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I admit your approach is much more direct (+1).  However, I also think that it's useful pedagogically to see a problem worked in a variety of ways, with the caveat that certain methods are indeed more roundabout.

Comment: I agree with you, and I think the downvote completely unjustified. (And as I said, I’m guessing about the reason for it.) I certainly don’t understand why you got **two** downvotes. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $s(t) = 2^{t^2} $. You can use implicit differentiation:

$$ s = 2^{t^2} \iff \log s = t^{2} \log 2 \iff_{\frac{d}{dt}} \frac{ s'}{s} = 2t \log 2$$

Hence,

$$ s' = s 2 t \log 2 \iff s' = 2^{t^2} 2 t \log 2$$

Comment: I am confused about how you went from the second last step to f inal step.

Comment: At the beginning $s$ was defined as equal to $2^{t^2}$. He just substituted the $s$ back in terms of $t$.

Comment: Ahhhh rightt, face palm, I forgot that in implicit diff, substituting a value back in at the end was a characteristic..

Answer (score 1):

Chain Rule: $\dfrac{ds}{dt}=(2^{t^2}\ln 2)\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}(t^2)\right)=(2^{t^2}\ln 2)(2t)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite $$s=2^{t^2}=e^{t^2 \log(2)}=e^{u(t)}$$ Then $$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{ds}{du}\times\frac{du}{dt}$$ with $$\frac{ds}{du}=e^{u(t)}=e^{t^2 \log(2)}$$ and $$\frac{du}{dt}=2t\log(t)$$